# java Filter class doFilter() is not being invoked

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, web.xml

**Hi there, I have created a Filter class and configure the web.xml as below:**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.web.auth.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>test-param</param-name>
        <param-value>This param is for testing</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/html/test/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**When I access the URL http://{myJBoss}/html/test/index.htm , 
LoginFilter's init() is called but not the doFilter()**

Here is the excerpt of my Filter class:

```
public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    log.debug("[201207bb] init");  //******This line can be seen in log file
    this.config = config;
    String testParam = config.getInitParameter("test-param");
    log.debug("test-param="+testParam);  //******* This is output correctly too
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.debug("[201207bb] doFilter");  //*****This line didn't appear in log file

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    //Get the IP address of client machine.
    String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

    //Log the IP address and current timestamp.
    log.debug("IP "+ipAddress + ", Time "  + new Date().toString());
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

**Does anyone has any idea why is this so? 
I have tried on a jsp too, same result.**

Comment: Do you mean doFilter method is not called when server initialize? What is your jsp url ?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your response. 
I just realize that I have set the wrong url-pattern.
Because I thought when init() is called means the url-pattern is hit. but seems it's not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
url-pattern is incorrectly set. 
init() is being called doesn't mean the url-pattern is set up correctly.

Comment: what url pattern fixed this?